# How can I view which ports are blocked and why the other ports are activated on a Linux Bridge?

Tags: linux, bridge, port

This was one of the questions I had on an exam about computer networks (translated from dutch). The answer should be one single command.

Comment: By 'bridge', do you mean interface? If yes, `netstat` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean a Linux operated device configured as bridge

Comment: the replacement for the obsolete command `brctl` is the command `bridge`. The second should tell you in one command with the right parameters.

Comment: seems like `bridge link show - list bridge port configuration` might be the answer here as it shows the current port configuration and flags, thank you!